# SOAPtoPOJOTransformer in mule esb

Tags: esb, mule

In my application client sends SOAP request to Mule ESB and so I want SOAPtoPOJOTransformer in my ESB so that will give POJO object to my component class.

Please give me a sample or code snippet for this transformer.

Thanks,
Narayanan

Answer (score 3):

CXF+JAXB will take care of that for you.

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Building+Web+Services+with+CXF

Answer (score 1):

In my app i have a xml declaring all the transformers i need to use so that i just reference them on my flows. See below. (You dont need to use iso-8859-1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mxml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.2/mule-xml.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.1/mule-vm.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mxml:jaxb-context
    name="jaxb-context"
    packageNames="my.package.v1:my.package.v2:soap.package" />

<mxml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer
    name="xml-to-object"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1"
    jaxbContext-ref="jaxb-context"
    ignoreBadInput="true" />

<mxml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer
    name="object-to-xml"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1"
    jaxbContext-ref="jaxb-context"
    returnClass="java.lang.String"
    ignoreBadInput="true" />

<byte-array-to-string-transformer
    name="byte-array-to-string"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1"
    returnClass="java.lang.String" />

<string-to-byte-array-transformer
    name="string-to-byte-array"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1"
    returnClass="byte[]" />

<custom-transformer
    name="xml-to-xml-stream-reader"
    class="org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToXMLStreamReader" />

<object-to-string-transformer name="object-to-string" />

<flow name="ByteArrayToObjectXml">

    <vm:inbound-endpoint
        path="myapp/conversor/byte-array-to-object-xml"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />

    <transformer ref="byte-array-to-string" />
    <transformer ref="xml-to-object" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write the data weave transformation to convert the xml into java. I am providing a example flow , you need to write similar transformation  code.

```
 <flow name="getDeltaFlightsFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/delta" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>

        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 http://soap.training.mulesoft.com/
---
{
    ns0#findFlight: {
        destination: flowVars.code as :string
    }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Delta_Service_Consumer" operation="findFlight" doc:name="Delta SOAP Reqst"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="fdbaa716-f263-4812-a153-6509b7407ee8" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%namespace ns0 http://soap.training.mulesoft.com/
---
{
    flights: payload.ns0#findFlightResponse.*return map ((return , indexOfReturn) -> {
        airlineName: return.airlineName,
        price: return.price,
        departureDate: return.departureDate,
        planeType: return.planeType,
        origin: return.origin,
        code: return.code,
        emptySeats: return.emptySeats,
        destination: return.destination
    })
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    </flow>
```